# SVG don't change color in hover

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I've been mapping my information and the problem occurs when I want to change the color of an SVG when the hover event occurs. This is my code:

```
{DataBanner.map((d, index) => (
   <div>
      <img
          src={d.icon}
          className="icon-image"
       />
   </div>
))}
```

css styles:

```
.icon-image:hover {
    stroke: white !important;
}
```

this is an example of how the SVG comes:

```
<svg width="39" height="57" viewBox="0 0 39 57" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M29.2799 47.7309V55.874H28.9356M10.1257 8.61963H1.29419V28.2326M1.29419 28.2326V55.874H28.9356M1.29419 28.2326L28.9356 55.874M10.8137 37.6377V1.39404H37.882V47.6161H20.7923M31.0791 13.4712V19.6147M28.0073 16.543H34.1509M25.467 14.7114C25.467 17.191 23.6909 19.2012 21.5 19.2012C19.3091 19.2012 17.533 17.191 17.533 14.7114C17.533 12.2318 19.3091 10.2217 21.5 10.2217C23.6909 10.2217 25.467 12.2318 25.467 14.7114ZM28.657 27.3237C28.657 31.1247 25.4527 31.3704 21.5 31.3704C17.5473 31.3704 14.343 31.1247 14.343 27.3237C14.343 23.5227 17.5473 20.4414 21.5 20.4414C25.4527 20.4414 28.657 23.5227 28.657 27.3237Z" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Because you are using svg as an image. You can't modify svg properties which is acting as an image now. Use svg as React components if you wanna modify them. Here is a blog: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-react/

Answer (score 1):

This would not work because the SVG is now imported as an image. To do this usually, you would have to paste the SVG code manually into your markup or import as a component.

I think you should go through this resource: https://www.sanity.io/guides/import-svg-files-in-react. It explains what you are trying to do and the solution I mentioned as well.

[Example of SVG in JSX attached. Attributes should be in camel case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ZW7.png)